# Cannot import 3rd party packages

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am running python 2.7.5 on OS X 10.9.4 . Whenever I install a package it installs to:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages

I installed py2neo using pip install and I am using pycharm as my IDE but I can't import the module I have installed when using it. In pycharm it says that my external libraries are located at:
System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/python/site-packages

which is not where the packages are being installed. Also, the import statement does work when I use the interpretor.

Comment: what interpreter are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to modify the python search path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/python/site-packages')

import py2neo
```